# Does this mean my hdd is dying?

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive

I am experiencing something really weird on my Win8.1 machine. I have 2 SSD on RAID0 where the system is installed on and a 2TB 5200rpm disk where I move the home directory to. These past days, after exactly 1hr from boot I will get a warning and windows will no longer be able to "see" this harddrive.

I did some SMART tests and got the following results:

CrystalDiskInfo:

[image]

WMIC:

[image]

My question is, is my HD really dying and I need to buy a new one to solve my problem, or is Windows the bad guy here and I can fix it doing something differently?

Comment: You have multiple tools saying its failing.  Your drive is failing.

Comment: Backup **now** while you can still read the disk (do not reboot first ... )

Comment: End up buying a new HDD and you guys were right, all my problems are gone!

Answer (score 3):

As hinted by David Postill...

**Do not reboot**

If you don't already have a backup...

Buy a new HD & a USB enclosure & get your data off that failing RAID while you still can.

SMART can lock you out of the drive altogether if you reboot & because it's a RAID, you will not be able to put it in an external enclosure to recover, because you will no longer be able to RAID it.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely trust your tools, the drive should be replaced.  Also HDs are so inexpensive nowadays, it seems silly to risk data loss when you could replace the drive so easily.  Then if you still have doubts the old drive is bad, you could reformat it and test it again or use it for something where drive failure wouldn't have any serious consequences.

Answer (score 0):

A rising "uncorrectable" sector count is oftentimes a sign of a slow cascade failure - somehow a tiny hole got knocked into a platter surface, and whatever WAS knocked out of that hole will sooner or later knock another hole somewhere, knocking out more debris. Which can knock futher holes - or even damage the read/write heads, either to a point where they stop working or where they themselves damage the platters. Rinse, repeat, incur data loss.

Answer (score 0):

Backup the data. If even while backing up any work occurs, use HDD Regenerator to respond sectors. It'll take time but you will be able to take backup of important stuff.

You may then try to completely wiped the HDD using same software and it may run 1 or 2 years more. Same happened to me two years ago.

P.S the drive is still working..